# Python /n Command

Tags: python

I am trying to do something very basic in Python, which is print a grid of *s to the user's preference.

```
x=int(input('Enter a x width: '))

while x<1:
    x=int(input('Enter a valid x width: '))


y=int(input('Enter a y width: '))

while y<1:
    y=int(input('Enter a valid y width: '))


for i in range(0,y):
    for i in range(0,x):
        print('*',end='')

    print('/n')
```

This produces an output of...

```
Enter a x width: 3
Enter a y width: 4
***/n
***/n
***/n
***/n
```

How would I remove the /n from the final printed representation, or what would be a better way to code this?

Comment: Just don't print it?  It doesn't look like you even need a newline (and the newline character is `\n`, by the way).

Comment: Why do you have a `print('/n')` if you don't *want* to print `/n`? Did you mean to print a line break `\n`?

Comment: Note that you actually *don't* want to print a line break, because python's `print` function automatically adds a line break anyway. Just use `print()` instead of `print('/n')`. `print('\n')` would give you empty lines between your asterisks.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Pretty much. I see that mostly what I did incorrectly was get the / and \ mixed up. However, it creates a line in between each level of stars, which is what I don't want. Currently, the output is correct apart from the fact that the /n is there.

Comment: Gotcha @Aran-Fey. It works now!